# How does one estimate the electrical power of a power plant?

Tags: power, generator

I've asked several people how a power plant creates power (i.e. currents and voltages) and I found that they were unsure. In addition, I’ve done several searches to get more information, and I was not able to find links to answer my questions. I am very familiar with ac power relationships and all the mathematics behind it.

1. When a power plant creates [power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_generation) like the [Hoover Dam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoover_Dam), it can provide 2.07 GW of electrical power. My question is what does this mean? I assume from Faraday’s law that the induced voltage across the generator coil produces an current, and this combination (P = VI) is the actual power but I'm sure that my thinking is naïve. Can someone roughly sketch out how the electrical power of a power plant is computed?
2. If possible, what kind of voltages and currents are power plants producing before the Step Up transformers? Of course, this varies from one power plant to another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is very general, and so is this answer.

> When a power plant creates power like the Hoover Dam, it can provide 2.07 GW of electrical power. My question is what does this mean? I assume from Faraday’s law that the induced voltage across the generator coil produces an current, and this combination (P = VI) is the actual power but I'm sure that my thinking is naïve. Can someone roughly sketch out how the electrical power of a power plant is computed?

### From a mechanical perspective

"2.07 GW" means that the peak output of the power plant is 2.07 GW. This is most likely a series of smaller units, say 20 × 100 MW units = 2.0 GW.

The generator is a converter of mechanical energy into electrical energy. So to generate 2.07 GW of electrical energy, an equivalent amount of mechanical energy has to be provided. In the case of the Hoover Dam, the mechanical energy is provided by water falling to a lower elevation, giving up its gravitational potential energy in the process.

From this perspective, you can think of the maximum electrical output power of a power plant as the maximum rate at which it can convert mechanical energy into electrical energy, factoring in the efficiency of the conversion process.

The rate at which mechanical power is generated is a mechanical engineer's problem. For a hydroelectric station, the mechanical power would depend on the water pressure, turbine size, and various design parameters. For a wind turbine, the mechanical power would be set by the radius of the blades. And so on.

### From an electrical perspective

Yes, the electrical energy produced follows Faraday's Law and Ohm's Law, though for an AC system, V and I are sinusoids which may not be in phase, and P ≠ VI. Rather, apparent power (volt-amperes) S = VI, and real power (watts) P = VI cos ɸ.

Other complications include electrical losses (per Ohm's law) and magnetic losses (eddy currents induced in metallic parts).

> If possible, what kind of voltages and currents are power plants producing before the Step Up transformers? Of course, this varies from one power plant to another.

### Regarding typical voltages

In my experience, small generators (i.e. diesel gen-sets) generate directly at the utilisation voltage, say 415 V here in Australia.

Larger power station units generate at a medium voltage like 11kV before stepping up to transmission voltage, i.e. 132 kV.

I imagine a medium voltage like 11kV is preferred vs. a high voltage like 33kV, because less insulation is required on the windings and the rotating parts may be physically lighter.

### Regarding typical currents

An aeroderivative gas turbine, i.e. the General Electric LM6000, is typically rated about 45 MW and might have a 60 MVA alternator attached to it. Calculation of the three-phase line current at 11kV is left as an exercise to the reader. Don't forget your √3.

A coal power station unit might be rated 400 MVA at 22kV. See "Tarong Power Station" in QLD, Australia, which consists of four large units like this. Again, calculation of the line current is left as an exercise.

---

Note: I am at home and hence don't have access to my reference material at work. The above numbers are indicative, so treat them with a grain of salt.

If you are curious as to the exact operating principles and theory of an AC generator, I would encourage you to look up a textbook on electric machinery. My personal favourite is Mulukutla Sarma's *Electric Machines*. Check your university library for a copy.

Comment: fantastic answer and loved your details about voltages and currents. Thanks for your suggestion on Sarma's book.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general question, I think it is too long and maybe not so useful to do a very detailed answer.

Basically electric power is generated by converting a different kind of power.
See [Electric Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power) on Wikipedia.

An hydroelectric plant works using the kinetic energy (converted from the potential energy) from the water.
See [Hydroelectricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroelectricity)

Voltage is created basically by rotating an electric motor (the same principle applies when a motor is running without any load and makes the current zero).
See the [Electric Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_generator)

Reading those links and following the sections (even by reading inside the links you are interested) should fulfil your curiosity.

The plant power is the maximum power it can provide (ideal conditions), summing the real power on the 3 phases.
The voltage at source can vary, but is fixed after the step up to 138kV or 230kV (can be elevated up to 700kV AC).
For a first idea look at: 
[Powerwise](http://www.powerwise.org.uk/ollieandsparky/teachers/OC3.html),
[CPS Energy](http://www.cpsenergy.com/Services/Generate_Deliver_Energy/Energy_Delivery/)

Comment: Your user icon and information appears below every question and answer you provide, thus you don't need to provide a signature. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/134987

Answer (score 0):

As we all know that energy can neither be created nor destroyed, but can be converted from one form to another, we come to the understanding that one form of energy goes through a specified process to come out as another.

Energy as we know can be derived from various sources including the sun, wind, heat, magnetic, water and etc.

From this we see that we are using machines or other devices to convert one of these into the other (usually electricity) to satisfy our end needs.

In electrical engineering, we call this place (where the machines are used to convert one form of energy to the other) as a power plant. Power plants can be of various types including hydro, solar, windmills, nuclear, thermal. In each of these power plants, the input is taken in (either by an engine, or by a solar cell, or by the blades of a wind mill etc) and is used to rotate a generator (or an alternator). The alternator generates electrical energy which is then then transmitted through cables and sent off to far flung places to be used.

This entire system which deals with the generation, transmission and distribution of electrical power is termed as a power system.

Answer (score -4):

Nuclear power plants create "power" by "splitting atoms." In more appropriate terms, this is [nuclear fission](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fission). They often use Uranium atoms, and they use [particle accelerators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_accelerator). The intense thermal energy generated from splitting the nucleus of Uranium, since Uranium is nearly the heaviest of atoms, and is non-radioactive.

The heat generated from the Uranium atoms' nuclear fission provides the thermal energy to propel mechanical turbines which, in turn, draw the mechanical power which, in turn, is transferred into electrical energy. This energy is then moved out of the plant and carried down power lines to smaller sub-stations across many AC transformers, and eventually to the power panel in your home.

Comment: Ordinary fission power plants don't use particle accelerators. Read section 1.6 of the wiki article you linked, and the resources it links to, for a primer on how they do work.

Comment: Why do you mention nulclear at all? The question is about the voltage and current produced by the electrical generators.

Comment: -1 Uranium is non-radioactive?